# Winterbash 2019

Tags: discussion

You may have noticed that another winter bash is going on: a snowflake icon in the top bar, maybe some hats coming around, see people wearing hats on their avatars.

In the previous years I have taken a lead in the winter bash, actively hunting for hats for me and for other users here on linguistics.se. However, this year I don't feel like hat hunting. I have found the [hat to wear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezjXs.png) already (and you cannot earn it in the winter bash, but you can edit your avatar if you want).

So expect fewer hats coming in this season.